# Impact of the transformation matrix distribution on linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution, transformation, uniform-distribution, random-matrices

Let $X$ be a $m\times n$ ($m$: number of records, and $n$: number of attributes) normalized dataset (between $0$ and $1$). Denote $Y=XR$, where $R$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, and $p<n$. I understand if $R$ was drawn randomly from Gaussian distribution, e.g., $N(0,1)$ then the transformation preserve the Euclidean distances between instances (all of the pairwise distances between the points in the feature space will be preserved). But what if $R\sim U(0,1)$, does the transformation still preserve the distance between instances?

Comment: What is $U(0,1)$?

Comment: Uniform distribution between $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have $m$ records $(X_i:1\leq i \leq m)$ of *normalized* $n$-dimensional data
(that is,
for each $i\leq m$,
we can write $X_i=(x^{(i)}_1,\ldots,x^{(i)}_n)\in[0,1]^n$).
Then,
multiplying any of the $X_i$ by a $n\times p$ matrix $R$ (where $p<n$) can be seen as *projecting* the vector $X_i$ onto $\mathbb R^p$.
Upon reading your question,
I understand that you're interested in projections that can be seen as somewhat *faithful*,
in that there will be little difference between the Euclidean distance between vectors $\|X_i-X_j\|_2$ in $\mathbb R^n$ and their projection $\|(X_i-X_j)R\|_2$ on $\mathbb R^p$.

---

First,
I believe your claim that if the entries of $R$ are i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables,
then the transformation preserves the distance is false.
To see this,
consider the simple counterexample:
Suppose we have two instances with two attributes $X_1=[1,1]$ and $X_2=[0,1]$.
Then,
we have that $$\|X_1-X_2\|_2=\sqrt{1^2+0}=1.$$
Let $R=[R_1,R_2]^{\top}$ be our transformation.
Then,
if we want the norm to be preserved,
it is necessary that
$$1=|X_1R-X_2R|=|(R_1+R_2)-R_2|=|R_1|,$$
in which case $R_1$ can only take the values $-1$ and $1$,
and hence is not $N(0,1)$.

---

What *could* be true is that the norm is preserved to some extent.
Indeed,
this would be a special case of the well-known **Johnson-Lindenstrauss Lemma** (see the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) article):

> Lemma: Let $0<\epsilon<1$,
>   and let $X=(x_1,\ldots,x_m)$ a set of $m$ points in $\mathbb R^N$.
>   Given $n<N$ which satisfies some technical conditions relating to $m$ and $\epsilon$,
>   there exists a linear map $T:\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb R^n$ such that for every $x_i,x_j\in X$,
>   we have that $$(1-\epsilon)\|x_i-x_j\|_2\leq\|Tx_i-Tx_j\|_2\leq(1+\epsilon)\|x_i-x_j\|_2.$$

Many of the proofs of the Johnson-Lindenstrauss have been done using random matrices,
effectively showing that some random matrices do indeed preserve the norm of vectors to some extent.

A lot of work has been done in this subject,
and it would be very time consuming to compile them here or even explain how they work.
I'll instead provide a few references for you to check it out.

1. [Database-friendly random projections: Johnson-Lindenstrauss with binary coins](http://users.soe.ucsc.edu/~optas/papers/jl.pdf), by
   Dimitris Achlioptas; and
2. [A Simple Proof of the Restricted Isometry Property for Random Matrices](http://users.ece.gatech.edu/~mdavenport/publications/bddw-ca-2008.pdf), by Richard Baraniuk, Mark Davenport, Ronald DeVore, and Michael Wakin.